# I need to this function to sum the number of unlimiited paramters

Tags: elisp

I am learning ELISP and this function should gather any number of parameters plus N and return the sum. This what I've got so far and I cannot figure out where my error is thanks. Also if a char is in the list it should just skip over and not add that to the value. I am using ELISP

```
(defun sum-numbers (n &rest L)
  (let (a 0)
    (if (not L) n
      (dolist (x L result)
    (if (integerp x)
        (setq a (+ x a)))))
    (setq a (+ a n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`let`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/let.html) incorrectly.

There might be other errors too, but your code is unreadable due to broken indentation. Hit `TAB` on every line to get the indentation right.

Comment: Or mark the whole region and then press `TAB` once to indent the whole region at once.  Then: `M-x untabify` to convert tabs to spaces.  Then you can copy and paste back into S.O.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections:

```
 (defun sum-numbers (n &rest L)
-  (let (a 0)
+  (let ((a 0))
     (if (not L)
         n
-      (dolist (x L result)
+      (dolist (x L (+ a n))
         (if (integerp x)
-            (setq a (+ x a)))))
-    (setq a (+ a n))))
+            (setq a (+ x a)))))))
```

(Outside of learning, you'd just use `+` which already sums an arbitrary number of arguments.)